# SQL Forgot Email PHP Page Giving Error `The multi-part identifier could not be bound. (severity 16) `

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, forms, email

I am trying to make a forgot password page using PHP for my website. Basically there is a form on the page that requires an email. The form looks for the email in my `staffportal` MSSQL table's column `email`. If the email exists in the table, it will retrieve the data from the `password` column from that same row. With the retrieved password, it will send an email containing the password to the email from that table row. Right now when I enter a correct email that exists in the `staffportal` table, it reads these errors:

```
Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: The multi-part identifier "kelsey.alon@s.ca" could not be bound. (severity 16) in D:\Hostingd990\html\staffportal\forgotemail.php on line 23

Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in D:\Hostingd90\html\staffportal\forgotemail.php on line 23

Warning: mssql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result resource in D:\Hostingd\html\staffportal\forgotemail.php on line 24
Thank you, ! we will get back to you.
```

Here is my full page code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
$conn=mssql_connect('gdom','Gd','d1!');
mssql_select_db('ar',$conn);
if (isset($_POST['forgotpass'])) {
$conn=mssql_connect('gdcom','GBder','Rd1!');
mssql_select_db('GBd',$conn);
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

        $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);

    }

 $email = $_POST['email'];
$querye = "SELECT password FROM staffportal WHERE email = ".$_POST['email']."";
$check = mssql_query($querye, $conn);
$check2 = mssql_num_rows($check);
echo "".$check2."";
//if the email doesn't exist it gives an error
if ($check2 = 0) {
echo '<script>alert("Sorry, the email '.$email.' is incorrect.");</script>';
} else {

print"<p>Thank you, $fname! we will get back to you.</p>";
print"<p>Today's date is $date.</p>";

$to = "".$email."";
$subject = "Financing for $fname $lname";
$body = " Date: $date \n\n Note: If any fields have been left blank it means the user did not input anything. \n\n First name: $fname \n Last name: $lname \n Company: $cname \n Email: $email \n Phone: $phone \n Fax: $fax \n Address: $address \n City: $city \n Province: $province \n Postal Code: $postal \n Equipment Type: $et \n Amount: $amount\n\n";
$headers = "From: info@gba.ca";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

}
} else {
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
      Email:<br />
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
 <br /><br />
      <input type="submit" id="forgotpass" value="Change Password" name="forgotpass"/>
</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any help. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$querye = "SELECT password FROM staffportal WHERE email = ".$_POST['email']."";
```

should be

```
$querye = "SELECT password FROM staffportal WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."'";
```

Comment: I am using MSSQL, so real_escape_string is non existent in an MSSQL_ version. But the errors are gone now, so thank you.

Comment: I see ok I will then remove the last part